# Why "index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1" when requesting this API using iterrows()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, api

In a CSV-file I have a column with 150k id-values, like below. I am trying to iterate through them and call the API using each value. The API has the request limit 5000/min.

```
OBJEKT_ID
id1
id2
id3
...
```

I then want to put the requested data (CLASS) into a new csv-file together with the corresponding ID in another column. Like below.

```
OBJEKT_ID,CLASS
id1,X
id2,Y
id3,Z
...,...
```

However, I am only able to create one row of data (like below) in the new csv-file before I get an error message.

```
OBJEKT_ID,CLASS
id1,X
```

The error message is "index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1". Why is this the case?

Here's the code:

```
object_df = pandas.read_csv("CSV_FILE.csv")

for index, row in object_df.iterrows():
    response = requests.get(
        f"url/{row[index]}",
        headers=headers)

    data = response.json()
    result = data["features"][0]["properties"]["agande"][0]["agare"]["analyser"]
    print(result)
    df = pandas.DataFrame()
    df['OBJEKT_ID'] = [row[index]]
    df['CLASS'] = [result]
    df.to_csv("collected_data.csv", index=False)
    time.sleep(0.0125)
    enter code here
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: row is a pandas series of length 1, so `row[index]` is out of bounds for index > 0.  You want `row[0]` rather than `row[index]` throughout your program.

Comment: As an aside (i.e. unrelated to your error), you could also use a [rate limiting module](https://pypi.org/project/ratelimit/)

Comment: @DarrylG Thank you! This helped. However, only the latest created row is being added to the collected_data.csv. Do you reckon why?

Edit: I got it working! Added mode ="a"

Comment: @mentace added an answer with corrections to your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Corrections for the following errors:

- row is a 1 element pandas series, so df['OBJEKT_ID'] = [row[index]] becomes out of bounds
- You're creating a new dataframe in each loop i.e. df = pandas.DataFrame()
- You're overwriting the csv file with each loop i.e. df.to_csv("collected_data.csv", index=False)

**Code**

```
object_df = pandas.read_csv("CSV_FILE.csv")

# Will hold the output data
output = {'OBJEKT_ID':[],
          'CLASS':[]}
for index, row in object_df.iterrows():
    response = requests.get(
        f"url/{row[index]}",
        headers=headers)

    data = response.json()
    result = data["features"][0]["properties"]["agande"][0]["agare"]["analyser"]
    
    print(result)
   
    output['OBJEKT_ID'].append(row[0])   # ID column
    output['CLASS'].append(result)       # class column
    
    time.sleep(0.0125)   # rate limiting (note: another option is to use a rate limiting modules
                         # such as https://pypi.org/project/ratelimit/)
    

# Create Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(output)

# Write to csv
df.to_csv("collected_data.csv", index=False)
```

**Alternative Method**

Use rate limiter and apply function

```
import requests

from ratelimit import limits

@limits(calls=4900, period=60)    # limits to 4900 calls per minute (backoff from 5000 max)
def call_api(row):                # function to process requests
    response = requests.get(
        f"url/row",
        headers=headers)          # note: headers not shown in posted code

    data = response.json()
    result = data["features"][0]["properties"]["agande"][0]["agare"]["analyser"]

    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception('API response: {}'.format(response.status_code))
    return response

# Create dataframe from CSV file    
object_df = pandas.read_csv("CSV_FILE.csv")

# Add class column (calling api on each row)
object_df['CLASS'] = object_df['OBJEKT_ID'].apply(call_api)

# Write to csv
df.to_csv("collected_data.csv", index=False)
```